# How to test for String with enter, apostrophe, quotation marks, many spaces etc when using robotframework

Tags: string, frameworks, enter, robotframework, apostrophe

I need to put text like above to variable in robotframework:

```
One two     "three" 'four'
five six *seven*
```

Can anyone put that for me if possible? I tried to find anything helpful on Robot Framework extrended user guide, but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Quote characters don't require any special formatting. Here's an example using the pipe-delimited plain text format:

```
| | ${string}= | set test variable | one two "three" 'four' \n five six *seven*
```